# Issues when vertically centering hyperlink within unordered list

Tags: html, css

I am using the following (simplified) code to vertically center a hyperlink within a UL. I know it may appear strange that I am applying the style to the hyperink rather than the li, but I require the entire list element to be clickable.

My code works just as intended, however as you can see on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LS2Qf/2/) the vertical centering is a little *off*.

Can anyone advise why this is? Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/">
            <label>Foo</label>
            <span>Bar</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

ul
{
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}

li, li a
{
    display: inline-block;
}

li a
{
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li label
{
    float: left;
}

li span
{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The line-height on your "ul" is whats moving the link up and down, if you increase it to about 120px it centers it.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `display:inline-block;` on `li a`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LS2Qf/3/)

Comment: Thank you @bookcasey. I do however require to have a label which is floated left - and this seems to be causing the issue. Could you kindly take a look at the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LS2Qf/7/) for more information?